# Cannot debug netstandard2.0 project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

I'm building a project with the following in the CSPROJ file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>basic_example</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <StartupObject>basic_example.LoopThroughInvalidFileChars</StartupObject>
      <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.14.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I'm interested in debugging a source file in this project using Visual Studio 2019.  Here are the details:

[image]

When I start the project without debugging, it compiles and runs fine. However when I place a breakpoint in my source code and I try to start *with* debugging, it basically runs my program and never stops at the breakpoint.

In my output window in Visual Studio, the following message appears:

> The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target > process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not > run on .NET Core.
> The program '[25444] basic-example.dll' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

However, I am *intentionally* setting the target framework to `netstandard2.0`. I.e. I would really like to debug it with the current project file.

Why won't Visual Studio allow me to debug this project?

Comment: `netstandard` projects cannot be `.exe` files because they don't target a _specific_ runtime.

Comment: netstandard is a library format for sharing between different .net frameworks. It doesn't make sense to make it executable. If you want to debug into it as a netstandard library then just create a dotnet core console app and call into the library in a normal way.

Comment: _[A refresher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks)_

Comment: @LukeBriner I was able to fix the problem. But I'm still confused as to what happens when I both set an `OutputType` of `Exe` and a `TargetFramework` of `netstandard2.0`. As far as I can tell the application will still build (only I can't debug it). Why don't I get an error when I specify the an `OutputType` of `Exe` and a `TargetFramework` of `netstandard2.0`? Why is it still able to run?

Comment: I'm not sure how you managed to do that but I don't think VS should let you choose exe + netstandard.

Comment: Hi @user32882, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as  an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @LukeBriner's and @Dai's comments I was able to solve the problem.

As @LukeBriner mentions:

> If you want to debug into it as a netstandard library then just create a dotnet core console app and call into the library in a normal way.

So that's what I did.

- I had to rename all methods named `Main` in my class library to something else (I used `Run`).
- I added a console app to the solution adjacent to the class library and added a project reference to the class library.
- I imported the class library in my console apps' `Program.cs` with a `using` statement. I called the class I wanted to debug in the `Main` method of `Program.cs`
- I modified the project file of the console application to look like the following:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>call_basic_example</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\openxml-exceptions\basic-example.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

- I modified the project file for the class library to look like the following:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>basic_example</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
      <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.14.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I was then finally able to debug into whichever method I wanted in the class library.